# React Native: what's the difference between Android Gradle Plugin in build.gradle file and Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

In my React Native project I'm using `react-native@0.63.4`, and following the migration guide from a previous version, I have the following line in my `android/build.gradle` file:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3')
```

When I recently opened the project in Android Studio it recommended I upgrade my Android Gradle Plugin from `4.1.2` to `4.1.3`.

**What I Want To Know:** What's the difference between the Android Gradle Plugin version referenced in my `build.gradle` file and the one in Android Studio? What effect does each have on the other, and how is each used in my app itself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's start with what build.gradle does:
Gradle is an open-source build automation tool that is designed to be flexible enough to build almost any type of software.

The Android Studio build system is based on Gradle, and the Android Gradle plugin adds several features that are specific to building Android apps.

Gradle build scripts are written using a Groovy or Kotlin DSL.

There are several differences on versions like:

- Incremental Builds
- Build Caching
- Incremental Subtasks
- Incremental Annotation Processing etc.

When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt which is telling you upgrade your project gradle. This is because you upgrade your Android Studio plugin, not the project. With this upgrade you can have some developed functionalities in gradle like above.

Comment: Re "Android Gradle plugin adds several features that are specific to building Android apps": Is the Android Gradle Plugin a plugin that Android Studio uses to leverage Gradle to build Android-specific apps?

Comment: Re "Gradle build scripts": This is the `buildScript` portion of `build.gradle`, right? Re "there are several differences on versions": is this version the classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3') version in the buildScript?

Comment: I didn't really understand your last paragraph. The prompt in Android Studio to upgrade from 4.1.2 to 4.1.3, you're saying that this is telling me to "upgrade my project gradle"? I don't understand what my project gradle is, or the rest of the paragraph unfortunately. Could you spell it out for me in a bit more detail, and specify what the different is between the version in the buildScript, and the version that I'm upgrading when I follow the prompt in Android Studio? Thanks very much.